# How to increment values (multiple in a continuous sequence) in a std::vector in O(1) time?

Tags: c++

**ELABORATED and SIMPLIFIED-----------------------------------------------------------**

The question I was asked in the coding interview required me to implement a stack. The skeleton of the class was provided with function definitions given as well. However, there was no logic inside the definitions.

```cpp
class myStack {
    f1(args) {//no logic I have to code it}
    f2(args) {//no logic I have to code it}
    ........
};
```

These functions had to be implemented with run-time O(1). I could get simpler ones done, however, there was an increment function which I could not. (Look at comment in code section below)

```cpp
void incre(int number, int increment) {
/* In this function, implement logic to implement increment of "number"
elements from the bottom of the stack by "increment".

incre(3, 5) -> means increment 3 elements from bottom of stack. Increment each by 5

*/
}
```

It was this function that posed a challenge as I had to do the operation in amortized O(1) time.

```
vec = 1 2 3 4 5
    + 1 1 1 1             // how to in O(1) time instead of loop?
vec = 2 3 4 5 5
```

The stack was implemented as a vector data structure inside the class by me. Since I implemented the function as a loop, I probably failed test cases.

So how to do it in O(1) time? Any data structure that could help?

Comment: Does it have to be vector? Can you use std::valarray? It supports operating on all elements in the array at once. It might get parallelised if the system supports it. 0(1) is a pretty lofty expectation and is usually reserved for situations where the values are pre-cached e.g Hashmap.

Comment: *"This probably is where I failed test cases."* -- I suspect an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Another option is to not actually increment the data right now. Instead, only increment them when you read each of them.

Comment: O(1) indicates that an algorithm always operates in the same amount of time. If your vector never changes size, then you can consider it an O(1) algorithm. But if the algorithm operates faster or slower depending on some input (like “'number' of values”), then it is O(n).

Comment: [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is an option, but I doubt it could be optimized as well as a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep If all elements of the stack get (read and) popped, then incrementing-on-read is still an O(n) operation, since there are n increments (eventually). Still, your delayed increment might be a good approach if we knew more of the *[real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)*. It's good if there are multiple increments. For `m` increments of `n` elements, the delayed increment is O(m+n), while using a loop for each iteration is O(mn). Good savings for large m, but not so much when m is 1, as in the question as written...

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Either `number` is considered fixed, in which case it is trivially O(1) or `number` is considered the limit parameter for the O notation, in which case it is obviously impossible to do better than O(number) since you want to modify `number` elements.

Comment: Assuming that `m` is `number` variable and `n` the size of the vector, your code complexity will always be **O(m)**. Big O notation is not about actual performance but a way to understand how execution time vary depending on the size of the data. For such code, you usually let the compiler optimize it using vectorization. Using smallest adequate integer type for your vector element might help make the code faster.

Comment: It could be any data structure. Incrementing them when only to read them would increase code complexity I think and might not yield results.

Answer (score 3):

The question lacks important details. In general, it’s impossible to increment an arbitrary range of elements in O(1) time. There must be additional constraints that make it possible.

The question mentions a stack but doesn’t go into further detail. Reading between the lines it could mean that the problem asks for a stack with regular push and pop operations plus bulk increment for a range. The stack “access pattern”, i.e. elements are consumed sequentially, enables increment in O(1) time.

The key idea is to maintain a parallel array of increments. I-th item, increments[i], encodes an argument to a bulk increment operation for the range [0, i]. It starts as 0 initially. Bulk increment operation simply updates a single item in increments, which is clearly O(1) operation.

Returning a container item a[i] clearly requires a summation of increments[i] till increments[N], where N is the total size of the container. Only the last item can be produced efficiently, but that’s ok for a stack.

The pop operation should increment increments[N-1] by increments[N] prior to reducing the container size by 1.

Answer (score -2):

As Nick answered on his post, you could try to record the increment with the corresponding value on the stack and update it just before retrieving, also passing the increment to the next position on the stack, skipping the loop entirely.

I will preserve my old answer just because it is interesting for people wanting to learn more about SIMD:

You can do that (**under very limited circumstances**) with [SIMD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSXVZZ_16.1.1/com.ibm.xlcpp1611.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_simd.html).

O(1) means constant time and you may be able to do that if your vector is very small. Lets say you have an aligned vector of floats with capacity of 4 and a **maximum size** of 4. You could load all the vector in a single register and use a single SIMD operation to update the values of the 4 positions simultaneously. It is probably not what you wanted, but it is worth mentioning it here. For the other cases where a loop is needed, using SIMD - despite not being O(1) -, can also speed up computation significantly, and as a matter of fact, it is frequently used for operating images in memory.

SSE and AVX (NEON too in ARM) instruction sets allow you to use a 128bits or 256bits register to place 2, 4 or 8 numbers and operate them simultaneously.

You can do that using OMP SIMD (more high level) or intrinsics (low level). Or just rely on compiler optimization.
If you want to use multiple threads, you can use OMP PARALLEL FOR (probably not worth in this case though).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241110/discussion-on-answer-by-adriel-jr-how-to-increment-values-multiple-in-a-continu).